# How get a process by know process name on mac os?

Tags: process, system, macos

How can i get a process by know process name on mac os?

Comment: You should put your code in an answer, and format it to make it easier to read. Then accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague. Can you define what you mean by "get a process"?

One method (depending on your definition): launch the Activity Monitor app in Applications/Utilities, and look up the process name in the list.

Comment: I finished it!
My sample:
bool IsInBSDProcessList(char *name)
// Return YES if given name process in process list .  Otherwise return NO
{
 assert( name != NULL);
 kinfo_proc *result;
 size_t count = 0;
 result = (kinfo_proc *)malloc(sizeof(kinfo_proc));
 if(GetBSDProcessList(&result,&count) == 0)
 {
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   kinfo_proc *proc = NULL;
   proc = &result[i];
   if(strcmp(name, proc->kp_proc.p_comm) == 0)
   {
    free(result);
    return true;
   }
  }
 }
 free(result);
 return false;
}

Answer (score 3):

Just reformatted Haley's answer:

```
// Return YES if given name process in process list . Otherwise return NO 
bool IsInBSDProcessList(char *name)    { 
  assert( name != NULL); 
  kinfo_proc *result; 
  size_t count = 0; 
  result = (kinfo_proc *)malloc(sizeof(kinfo_proc)); 
  if(GetBSDProcessList(&result,&count) == 0) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
      kinfo_proc *proc = NULL; 
      proc = &result[i]; 
      if (strcmp(name, proc->kp_proc.p_comm) == 0) { 
        free(result);
        return true;
      }
    }
  } 
  free(result);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think that malloc() is superfluous.

Comment: Rereading this answer and adding why `malloc()` is superfluous: allocating `kinfo_proc` on the stack and taking a pointer also would work.

Comment: If somebody has problems finding the GetBSDProcessList function. Here it is: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
ps -eaf
```

from a console

Comment: no,not from a console
thx same